# Where are keywords defined in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was looking at the Ruby documentation, and am wondering if everything is an object then 'keywords' are objects as well, correct?  And if so, where are they defined in ruby?

The following page totally confused me caused it showed the object with all the keywords in it, however this is not the official Object that is used by all classes, is this mixed-in somehow from a different class??

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html

I guess there are lots of questions above, the main one is: how do ruby keywords get into ruby?

Comment: If you take "everything is object" in that sense, then it is not true. Keywords are not objects. And another thing that is not an object that I was confused at the beginning is a block. Blocks are not objects either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The keywords are not objects but defined in the parser which can be found in `parse.y` in the Ruby source. Here's the relevant part from that file:

```
reswords    : keyword__LINE__ | keyword__FILE__ | keyword__ENCODING__
        | keyword_BEGIN | keyword_END
        | keyword_alias | keyword_and | keyword_begin
        | keyword_break | keyword_case | keyword_class | keyword_def
        | keyword_defined | keyword_do | keyword_else | keyword_elsif
        | keyword_end | keyword_ensure | keyword_false
        | keyword_for | keyword_in | keyword_module | keyword_next
        | keyword_nil | keyword_not | keyword_or | keyword_redo
        | keyword_rescue | keyword_retry | keyword_return | keyword_self
        | keyword_super | keyword_then | keyword_true | keyword_undef
        | keyword_when | keyword_yield | keyword_if | keyword_unless
        | keyword_while | keyword_until
        ;
```

If you want to know more about the Ruby parser, look at the presentation [Hacking parse.y](http://www.slideshare.net/ujihisa/hacking-parsey-rubyconf-2009) from RubyConf 2009 or [Parse.y famtour](http://rubykaigi.org/2011/en/schedule/details/18S01) from Ruby Kaigi 2011.

Also, a lot of the methods that are available everywhere (like e.g. `puts`) are defined in the [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html) module.

EDIT: There's also a [list of key words in the documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/keywords.rdoc), thanks @antinome for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the great info...lol...nice presentation from Ruby Kaigi 2011, I need to brush up on my Japanese. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, here's where the ruby documentation lists the keywords: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/keywords.rdoc

Comment: @antinome Thanks, included that in the answer. :)