# Where is the 'while' loop defined in Ruby standard modules/classes?

Tags: ruby

For example, `puts` is defined as a method of Kernel. Therefore, one can use Kernel.puts("anything"). The same applies to `loop`:

```
Kernel.loop do
   puts "forever"
end
```

That said, where is `while` defined? Is `while` a method? If not, what is it exactly?

Yes, it's a dumb question, but I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Ruby is build on top of C, so I'm guessing the while loop was inherited. The loop do structure is specific to Ruby, and kernel often hosted these methods

Comment: [`while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop) is a control expression.  It's also a ruby [`keyword`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html).

Comment: `while` is a keyword. Other keywords involving control flow are `if`, `else`, `elsif`, `then`, `unless`, `until`, `for`, `case`, `when`, `next`, `break` and `return`.

Comment: "Ruby Programming" says in its section about **Loops** (p.344 of my copy) says "*loop*, which iterates its associated block, is not a language construct--it is a method in module *Kernel*."  By inference, `while`, `until`, and `for`, which were discussed before that, *are* language constructs.

Comment: Apparently, keywords are defined in the parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446150/where-are-keywords-defined-in-ruby

Comment: and this is what it is compiled to in cruby https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c3ceb1bff26a0dc59d7b93647e3a58c57e7c0440/compile.c#L4109-L4112

Comment: @orde would you like to add an answer below?

Comment: @phss If that's the answer, this should be marked as a duplicate :P